# Where do I get Visual Studio 15.4 that I need for pyTorch 0.4.1

Tags: visual-studio, pytorch, ffi, cffi

I have a problem with the following dependency chain:

- MedicalDetectionToolkit (MDT) needs pyTorch 0.4.1 since in pyTorch 1.0 torch.utils.ffi is depricated
- pyTorch 0.4.1 needs CUDA 9.0 (does not work with 10.0)
- CUDA 9.0 does not work with Visual Studio > 15.4
- Visual Studio 15.4 is not available anywhere, the MSVS installer will install 15.9

The Visual Studio Installer allows to install the "Compiler Tools 15.4" side-by.side, but MDT uses torch.utils.ffi at some point, which just uses the 15.9.

So

How do I install Visual Studio 15.4?

Or

How do I tell `torch.utils.ffi` to use the 15.4 compiler?

(MedicalDetectionToolkit will not be updated by the author. I may try it, but would like to have a working version first.)

Comment: Does this help? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/side-by-side-minor-version-msvc-toolsets-in-visual-studio-2017/

Comment: Why do you need to use old pytorch, where you found these requirements?

Comment: @prosti The Medical Dection Toolkit requires 0.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.0)" available on 
https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202017

You may first have to join the "Essentials" program. After joining the downloads became visible.